# The Key "Unit Of Measure" is not sorted alphabetically

Tags: typescript

Maybe I am loosing my mind but I keep getting an error that says:

```
Failed to compile
/Users/matthewlemke/Desktop/Projects/novamud-mudman-workspace/web/react- 
app/src/Components/Main/Admin/Products/AdminProducts.tsx
(74,9): The key 'UnitOfMeasure' is not sorted alphabetically
```

I have moved it around everywhere and I dont get it, this is what makes sense to me:

```
public state = {
    editing: false,
    expenseTypes: [] as IEBPExpenseType[],
    formattedExpenseTypeData: undefined as unknown as IList,
    formattedProductsData: this.productList,
    modal: false,
    products: this.products,
    regionData: this.productList,
    regions: [] as IRegion[],
    rowIndex: 0,
    // selectedUnitOfMeasure: [] as boolean[],
    showDefault: false,
    showExpense: false,
    showRegion: true,
    showUOM: true,
    UnitOfMeasure: this.UnitOfMeasure,
};
```

what am I not seeing here?

Comment: Have you tried a lower-case `u`? I don't know typescript but that seems to stick out to me.

Comment: Trying that now actually, Thats the only thing I can think of but I have to replace it in a lot of places lol.

Comment: Most editors have a find-and-replace that works across multiple files.

Answer (score 3):

The [`object-literal-sort-keys` linting rule](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/object-literal-sort-keys/) is case-sensitive. You can disable this by using the `ignore-case` config option.

The reason you're getting an error is because uppercase letters have a lower ASCII value than lowercase letters, so `UnitOfMeasure` should be first (since it's the only uppercase property name in your example).

It might also help to look at an [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/) in order to get a better understanding.

Comment: This was very helpful! And thanks for the ASCII table, that is a great reference point that I dont often think about enough to use in problem solving.